# Can I count properties before I create an object? In the constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, constructor

can I count the amount of properties in a class before I create an object? Can I do it in the constructor?

```
class MyClass
{  
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        int count = //somehow count properties? => 3
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
class MyClass
{  
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        int count = this.GetType().GetProperties().Count();
        // or
        count = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties().Count();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah thats how easy it is. Sry, I thought its much harder - thought its easy to read the amount of properties after I created an object but before I dont have an object I thought its harder. Thx

Comment: The type is known to the runtime even if you don't have an instance of it.

Answer (score 6):

That's possible using reflection as BigYellowCactus has shown. But there's no need to do this in the constructor every time as the number of properties never changes.

I would suggest doing it in a static constructor (called only once per type):

```
class MyClass
{  
    public string A{ get; set; }
    public string B{ get; set; }
    public string C{ get; set; }

    private static readonly int _propertyCount;

    static MyClass()
    {
        _propertyCount = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties().Count();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public MyClass()
{
    int count = GetType().GetProperties().Count();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this for count no of properties your class contain**

```
Type type = typeof(YourClassName);
int NumberOfRecords = type.GetProperties().Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

With reflection you can check the properties of the class:

```cs
typeof(ClassName).GetProperties().Length;
```